# Inherit CSS from the view in Webix

Tags: javascript, css, user-interface, inheritance, webix

I'm completely stuck with this. Trying to create a custom view that inherits from the search field:

```
webix.protoUI({
  name:"ctext",
  defaults:{
    maxWidth:190
  },
...
},webix.ui.search)
```

Here, take a look: http://webix.com/snippet/89ca3d39

As you can see, CSS-class from the parent view does not load. How can I fix this?

Comment: Not sure if you mean this. 

`defaults:{
     maxWidth:190,height:70
   },`

[demo](http://webix.com/snippet/16d8cfe8)

Comment: @DarioSandoval 
Not at all. Anyway, I've corrected the snippet as you suggested for the clearer illustration.
Point is that CSS does not inherit from the parent [search view](http://webix.com/snippet/20cffdbb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
 name:"ctext",
 $cssName:"search", 
 defaults:{. . .},
```

if you want to apply CSS-class from another control

[Snippet](http://webix.com/snippet/8d4786ee) and the [docs](http://docs.webix.com/api__ui.uploader_$cssname_other.html)